# Java import packages understanding

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

i'm learning Java for one year now and this question is confusing me.

At the moment i'm working with Java Swing and i want to know why i have to write the line

```
import java.awt.event.*;
```

when i want to use the actionListener even when i've already imported the whole awt package before :/

```
import java.awt.*
```

why do i have to tell the compiler to import a Sub-package (is it the right name?), for instance the event package, when i already imported everything under the awt package?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Because java.awt and java.awt.event are two different packages. import java.awt.* imports classes from the java.awt package. Not from java.awt.event. Google for "java tutorial import", click on the first link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html. And surprisingly enough, it has the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because each package is separate. They don't have a parent-sub relationship.

```
import java.awt;
```

doesn't mean that `java.awt.event` is imported.

Comment: It would be great to understand the structure of java libraries!

Comment: @Murad_Alm. It has nothing to do with 'structure'. It has to do with the fact that importing an entire package doesn't import its sub-packages, which in turn is due to the fact that that's the way they designed it.

Comment: Tanks a lot mate!